# Any idea how fast Mag 1 is from Skyward?

Tags: books, skyward

I've ready through the book Skyward once and then skimmed it a few times, but can't find any number related to Mag 1, which is described as their normal combat speed. I might just be missing a sentence, but since I only have a paper version I can't exactly do ctrl+f and search through every reference to Mag 1. I also only have the first book, so if you've read the whole series and can find it in a different book that would be helpful.

How fast is Mag 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Peter Ahlstrom (who is the editorial assistant to Brandon Sanderson) Mag is **300 miles per hour** (around 482 kilometers an hour).

He answered the same question [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/PeterAhlstrom/status/1065021219148197888):

[image: Screen shot of tweets between user Adonalsium and Peter Ahlstrom.]

Comment: I have not read the series so I'm unsure if the tweet contains spoilers. Sorry if that is the case

Comment: Nope, there's no spoilers there. Though there is a stunt called "Ahlstrom loop" in the books and now I think I know where the name's from :)